# How to sum some elements of another array into a new one to create a moving average

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, sum, element

I have always used range references on worksheets for calculations, but am now starting to use arrays to work with data, due to how much faster they can be. I am going to be dealing with billions of computations, so I need to do as much as possible in memory.  In the provided code snippet, I am trying to get "SMA_MIN_Array" to calculate a 50 period moving average of the preceding 50 values of the array named vArray. Does anybody know how to accomplish it? Here is what I have so far, and I cannot get it to work. The "Sum(vArray(j,j+49)/50) is the culprit. I know that isn't right, but I needed to put down an idea for someone with way more array experience than me to interpret what I actually want.  I just don't know how to translate this into summing items 1 through 50 and dividing the total by 50. And the second element of the SMA_MIN_Array would then calculate the average of elements 2 through 51, etc.  Any ideas? Here is a snippet of some code that I have tried: (If you live in Dallas, I will buy you a drink of your choice for help on this problem!)

Thanks,
 Nick

```
Option Base 1
Sub Main()
Dim Mainwb As Workbook
Set Mainwb = ThisWorkbook


Dim Last_Row As Long
Last_Row = Mainwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Mainwb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F5:F" & Last_Row)

Dim vArray() As Variant
vArray = rng

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(vArray, 1) To UBound(vArray, 1)
Next

    Dim newWorkbook As Workbook
    Set newWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Add

    With newWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range(.Cells(5, 8), .Cells(Last_Row, 8)).Value = vArray
    End With


Dim SMA_MIN_Array() As Variant
ReDim SMA_MIN_Array(1 To Last_Row - 50, 1 To 1)
For j = 1 To Last_Row - 50
SMA_MIN_Array(j, 1) = Sum(vArray(j, j + 49)) / 50
Next


With newWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
.Range(.Cells(55, 10), .Cells(Last_Row, 10)).Value = SMA_MIN_Array
End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The macro below shows how to achieve the result I believe you seek.

I set Cell A1 of worksheet MoveAvg to `=Rand() * 1000`.  I dragged that down to Cell A1500.  I did a Paste Special of Values only for this range so the random values were fixed.

I set Cell C50 to the average of Cells A1:50.  I dragged that down.

I ran the macro below which creates an array containing the moving averages.  This array is written to column E starting at row 50.

The image below shows that the values calculated by Excel match those calculated by the macro.

[image: Sample test data]

However, VBA is not the language to use is you are performing “billions of computations.”

I answered a recent question that involved calculating 8,063 million values and writing them to disk with 1 million values per file.  Calculating and saving 50 million values with VBA took 13 minutes, 15 seconds.  Multiplying up suggests a total time for all 8,063 million values of nearly 14 days, 20 hours.  With VB.Net, calculating and storing all 8,063 million values took 51 minutes.

Reading from and writing to an Excel workbook with VB.Net is slower that with VBA.  But once the data is within VB.Net arrays, calculations are thousands of times faster.

VB.Net is an upgrade of VBA so the learning curve is not steep.  The Express version of VB.Net is free to download and you can distribute any programs you write if you register.

I leave you to think about it.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CalcMovingAvg()

  Dim MoveAvg() As Double
  Dim RowTVLast As Long
  Dim RowTVCrnt As Long
  Dim TestValues As Variant
  Dim TotalRunning As Double

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculate = False

  With Worksheets("MoveAvg")
    RowTVLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    TestValues = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(RowTVLast, 1)).Value
  End With

  ReDim MoveAvg(1 To UBound(TestValues, 1) - 49, 1 To 1)

  TotalRunning = 0
  For RowTVCrnt = 1 To 50
    TotalRunning = TotalRunning + TestValues(RowTVCrnt, 1)
  Next

  MoveAvg(1, 1) = TotalRunning / 50

  For RowTVCrnt = 51 To UBound(TestValues, 1)
    TotalRunning = TotalRunning - TestValues(RowTVCrnt - 50, 1) + TestValues(RowTVCrnt, 1)
    MoveAvg(RowTVCrnt - 49, 1) = TotalRunning / 50
  Next

  With Worksheets("MoveAvg")
    .Range(.Cells(50, 5), .Cells(RowTVLast, 5)).Value = MoveAvg
  End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.Calculate = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was beginning to wonder if I would have to implement SAS to do this for me.  I will obtain VB.Net as I am getting to heavy modeling and theoretical hypotheses at work.  I truly appreciate your assistance, and look forward to learning VB.Net!  Your help is invaluable.  I hope you have a great day!

Nick